# mvvm light async call in viewmodel constructor

Tags: azure, mvvm, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

I'm developing a win phone 8 app using portable version of mvvmlight.

In the creation of a ViewModel I have to do a call to a service that read data from a Azure Mobile Service using the Azure Mobile Service Sdk.

Sdk apis use async /await to do the work, and I can't do async calls in the ViewModel or in  Service costructor.

The code is like this:

```
    public  ListaArtiModel(INavigate navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;

        ArtiMarzialiService artiService = new ArtiMarzialiService();
        List<ArteMarziale>risultato = await artiService.ListaArti();

    }
```

and the compiler tells

Error   1   The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

How can I solve this?
thanks,
  Luca

Answer (score 2):

I have a ["task notifier" type](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NotifyTaskCompletion) in my [AsyncEx library](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx) that is essentially an `INotifyPropertyChanged` wrapper for `Task<T>`. You can use it like this:

```
public  ListaArtiModel(INavigate navigationService)
{
    _navigationService = navigationService;

    ArtiMarzialiService artiService = new ArtiMarzialiService();
    Arti = NotifyTaskCompletion.Create(LoadArti(artiService));
}

private async Task<ObservableCollection<ArtiMarziali>> LoadArti(ArtiMarzialiService artiService)
{
    return new ObservableCollection<ArtiMarziali>(await artiService.ListaArti());
}

public INotifyTaskCompletion<ObservableCollection<ArtiMarziali>> Arti { get; private set; }
```

Then your databinding code can use `Arti.Result`, `Arti.IsFaulted`, `Arti.ErrorMessage`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should redesign your ViewModel to have a `LoadDataAsync()` or `InitializeAsync()` method that is used to set up the ViewModel

In general, class constructors should be kept as simple as possible and you should avoid doing any long running or potentially exception-prone work in the constructor

Comment: But some data binding on the view model is async in nature. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think i found a better solution:

1. declared the service interface this way:

   ```
   void ListaArti(Action<List<ArtiMarziali>, Exception> callback);
   ```
2. implemented it this way:

   ```
   public async void ListaArti(Action<List<ArtiMarziali>, Exception> callback)
   {
       Exception err = null;
       List<ArtiMarziali> risultato = null;
       try
       {
           risultato = await MobileService.GetTable<ArtiMarziali>().ToListAsync();
       }
       catch (Exception ex) 
       {
           err = ex;
       }
       callback(risultato, err);
   }
   ```
3. called the service in the viewmodel constructor this way:

   ```
   IArtiMarzialiService artiService = new ArtiMarzialiService();
   artiService.ListaArti((arti, err) =>
   {
     if (err != null)
     {
       /// if there is an error should create a property and bind to it for better practices
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(err.ToString());
     }
     else
     {
       /// set the property
       Arti = new ObservableCollection<ArtiMarziali>(arti);
     }
   });
   ```

using an async function that returns a void I don't have to use the await statement in the caller, and I use the callback to set the property in the viewmodel when the data are available.